# View output from long running external process called from Python

Tags: python, popen

I have a very long running process that I would like to call from a Python program.  This process outputs a lot of information to stdout.  I would like to see the output from my called program on the command line as it is running.  I have read about Popen, and tried

```
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

and variants of this, but the output from cmd doesn't get displayed until cmd is finished running.

How do I view the output of cmd while cmd is running?

Comment: This question is closely related. I think it solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

Comment: So can I convert my own post to a comment or do I need some ridiculous number of points to do that?  ;)

Comment: This is almost the same.  The only difference is that the top answer in the thread you pointed me to will continue to spawn processes.  I do want the process to block until it is finished, but I just want to see output along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out by using part of what was mentioned in the comments, and combined that with the following

```
# read line without blocking
while not p.poll():
    try: 
        line = q.get_nowait() # or q.get(timeout=.1)
    except Empty:
        pass # Do nothing
    else: # got line
        print line
```